# No module named '_geoslib'

Tags: python-3.x

How can I solve this problem?
My code is :

`from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap`

The error message is :

```
  ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d9467465a3b6> in <module>
----> 1 from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py in <module>
     37 import numpy as np
     38 import numpy.ma as ma
---> 39 import _geoslib
     40 import functools
     41 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_geoslib'
```

Answer (score 0):

Conda installing basemap fixed this for me:

```
conda install -c conda-forge basemap
```

Ref: https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/421